# Redirecting after a json call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I have a login window on my application. The user enters login details and these are 
sent to the server as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            url: href,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serializeArray(),
            success: function (json, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                json = json || {};
                if (json.success) {
                    switch (action) {
                        case "xxx":

                        <more code here>

                        default:
                            location = json.redirect || location.href;
                    }
                } else {
```

When I trace the code I see it go to the row starting with "location =".  I see that json.redirect is set to 
null and location.href is set the the current URL.

I would like it to redirect to the correct URL but when I allow the code to continue it does nothing and 
does not go to any new URL.

Am I missing something from the way I do the redirect?

Comment: make sure that `json.redirect` has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but don't you need to use `window.location` not just `location`?

Comment: I tried this and it makes no difference. I wonder if it is not changing the location because it's already at that location. However what I need is a reload.

Comment: The page won't reload if the location is the same.  You might need something like `if (window.location == location.href) window.reload() else window.location = json.redirect;` perhaps.